# Reduce time taken to get feasible solution

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

[image]

I have such a set of nonlinear inequalities with m variables, Please suggest some good method to get some feasible solutions, where a[i]'s belong to [-5,5].So please suggest an approach, to get feasible solutions of a[i] in the shortest time possible.

Code which uses the NMinimize to solve more complicated inequations. In this NMinimize is not able to do the needful. 
Error Prompt : The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points. \
Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a better solution.

```
expr2 = (-2 a[3] (62047 a[4] + 62047 a[5] + 2353552 (a[7] + a[8])) + 
   a[1] (-62047 a[5] + 124094 a[6] - 2353552 (a[8] - 2 a[9])) + 
   a[2] (62047 a[4] + 124094 a[6] + 2353552 (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   1426022 (-2 a[6] (a[7] + a[8]) - a[4] (a[8] - 2 a[9]) + 
      a[5] (a[7] + 2 a[9])))/(a[3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + 
   a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (-2 a[3] (47251 a[4] + 47251 a[5] + 2272349 (a[7] + a[8])) + 
   a[1] (-47251 a[5] + 94502 a[6] - 2272349 (a[8] - 2 a[9])) + 
   a[2] (47251 a[4] + 94502 a[6] + 2272349 (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   1374466 (-2 a[6] (a[7] + a[8]) - a[4] (a[8] - 2 a[9]) + 
      a[5] (a[7] + 2 a[9])))/(a[3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + 
   a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (-6 a[3] (60403 a[4] + 60403 a[5] + 217313 (a[7] + a[8])) + 
   3 a[1] (-60403 a[5] + 120806 a[6] - 217313 (a[8] - 2 a[9])) + 
   3 a[2] (60403 a[4] + 120806 a[6] + 217313 (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   1070056 (-2 a[6] (a[7] + a[8]) - a[4] (a[8] - 2 a[9]) + 
      a[5] (a[7] + 2 a[9])))/(a[3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + 
   a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (-2 a[3] (153431 a[4] + 153431 a[5] + 651525 (a[7] + a[8])) +
    a[1] (-153431 a[5] + 306862 a[6] - 651525 (a[8] - 2 a[9])) + 
   a[2] (153431 a[4] + 306862 a[6] + 651525 (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   489336 (-2 a[6] (a[7] + a[8]) - a[4] (a[8] - 2 a[9]) + 
      a[5] (a[7] + 2 a[9])))/(a[3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + 
   a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[3] (487441232 a[4] - 221321649 a[5] + 
      2353552 (7856 a[7] - 3567 a[8])) + 
   a[2] (-243720616 a[4] + 221321649 a[6] - 
      2353552 (3928 a[7] - 3567 a[9])) + 
   3928 a[1] (62047 a[5] - 124094 a[6] + 
      2353552 (a[8] - 2 a[9])) + 
   1426022 (a[6] (7856 a[7] - 3567 a[8]) + 
      3928 a[4] (a[8] - 2 a[9]) + 
      a[5] (-3928 a[7] + 3567 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[3] (371203856 a[4] - 168544317 a[5] + 
      2272349 (7856 a[7] - 3567 a[8])) + 
   a[2] (-185601928 a[4] + 168544317 a[6] - 
      2272349 (3928 a[7] - 3567 a[9])) + 
   3928 a[1] (47251 a[5] - 94502 a[6] + 
      2272349 (a[8] - 2 a[9])) + 
   1374466 (a[6] (7856 a[7] - 3567 a[8]) + 
      3928 a[4] (a[8] - 2 a[9]) + 
      a[5] (-3928 a[7] + 3567 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (3 a[
     3] (474525968 a[4] - 215457501 a[5] + 
      217313 (7856 a[7] - 3567 a[8])) + 
   3 a[2] (-237262984 a[4] + 215457501 a[6] - 
      217313 (3928 a[7] - 3567 a[9])) + 
   11784 a[1] (60403 a[5] - 120806 a[6] + 
      217313 (a[8] - 2 a[9])) + 
   1070056 (a[6] (7856 a[7] - 3567 a[8]) + 
      3928 a[4] (a[8] - 2 a[9]) + 
      a[5] (-3928 a[7] + 3567 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[3] (1205353936 a[4] - 547288377 a[5] + 
      651525 (7856 a[7] - 3567 a[8])) + 
   a[2] (-602676968 a[4] + 
      3 (182429459 a[6] - 217175 (3928 a[7] - 3567 a[9]))) + 
   3928 a[1] (153431 a[5] - 306862 a[6] + 
      651525 (a[8] - 2 a[9])) + 
   489336 (a[6] (7856 a[7] - 3567 a[8]) + 
      3928 a[4] (a[8] - 2 a[9]) + 
      a[5] (-3928 a[7] + 3567 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[3] (-703178651 a[4] + 5584230 a[5] - 
      2353552 (11333 a[7] - 90 a[8])) - 
   45 a[2] (62047 a[4] + 124094 a[6] + 2353552 (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   1426022 (-11333 a[6] a[7] + 45 a[4] a[8] + 90 a[6] a[8] + 
      11333 a[4] a[9] - 45 a[5] (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   a[1] (2792115 a[5] + 703178651 a[6] + 
      2353552 (45 a[8] + 11333 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (a[5] a[7] - a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (-a[6] a[7] + a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (a[6] a[8] - a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[3] (-535495583 a[4] + 4252590 a[5] - 
      2272349 (11333 a[7] - 90 a[8])) - 
   45 a[2] (47251 a[4] + 94502 a[6] + 2272349 (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   1374466 (-11333 a[6] a[7] + 45 a[4] a[8] + 90 a[6] a[8] + 
      11333 a[4] a[9] - 45 a[5] (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   a[1] (2126295 a[5] + 535495583 a[6] + 
      2272349 (45 a[8] + 11333 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (a[5] a[7] - a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (-a[6] a[7] + a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (a[6] a[8] - a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (3 a[
     3] (684547199 a[4] - 5436270 a[5] + 
      217313 (11333 a[7] - 90 a[8])) + 
   135 a[2] (60403 a[4] + 120806 a[6] + 217313 (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   1070056 (11333 a[6] a[7] - 45 a[4] a[8] - 90 a[6] a[8] - 
      11333 a[4] a[9] + 45 a[5] (a[7] + 2 a[9])) - 
   3 a[1] (2718135 a[5] + 684547199 a[6] + 
      217313 (45 a[8] + 11333 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[3] (-1738833523 a[4] + 
      15 (920586 a[5] - 43435 (11333 a[7] - 90 a[8]))) - 
   45 a[2] (153431 a[4] + 306862 a[6] + 651525 (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   489336 (-11333 a[6] a[7] + 45 a[4] a[8] + 90 a[6] a[8] + 
      11333 a[4] a[9] - 45 a[5] (a[7] + 2 a[9])) + 
   a[1] (6904395 a[5] + 
      7 (248404789 a[6] + 93075 (45 a[8] + 11333 a[9]))))/(a[
     3] (a[5] a[7] - a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (-a[6] a[7] + a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (a[6] a[8] - a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (419 a[3] (62047 a[4] + 62047 a[5] + 2353552 (a[7] + a[8])) +
    a[1] (367380287 a[5] - 25997693 a[6] + 
      2353552 (5921 a[8] - 419 a[9])) + 
   1426022 (-5921 a[5] a[7] + 419 a[6] a[7] + 5921 a[4] a[8] + 
      419 a[6] a[8] - 419 (a[4] + a[5]) a[9]) - 
   a[2] (367380287 a[4] + 25997693 a[6] + 
      2353552 (5921 a[7] + 419 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (419 a[3] (47251 a[4] + 47251 a[5] + 2272349 (a[7] + a[8])) +
    a[1] (279773171 a[5] - 19798169 a[6] + 
      2272349 (5921 a[8] - 419 a[9])) + 
   1374466 (-5921 a[5] a[7] + 419 a[6] a[7] + 5921 a[4] a[8] + 
      419 a[6] a[8] - 419 (a[4] + a[5]) a[9]) - 
   a[2] (279773171 a[4] + 19798169 a[6] + 
      2272349 (5921 a[7] + 419 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (1257 a[
     3] (60403 a[4] + 60403 a[5] + 217313 (a[7] + a[8])) + 
   3 a[1] (357646163 a[5] - 25308857 a[6] + 
      217313 (5921 a[8] - 419 a[9])) + 
   1070056 (-5921 a[5] a[7] + 419 a[6] a[7] + 5921 a[4] a[8] + 
      419 a[6] a[8] - 419 (a[4] + a[5]) a[9]) - 
   3 a[2] (357646163 a[4] + 25308857 a[6] + 
      217313 (5921 a[7] + 419 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (419 a[
     3] (153431 a[4] + 153431 a[5] + 651525 (a[7] + a[8])) + 
   a[1] (908464951 a[5] - 64287589 a[6] + 
      651525 (5921 a[8] - 419 a[9])) + 
   489336 (-5921 a[5] a[7] + 419 a[6] a[7] + 5921 a[4] a[8] + 
      419 a[6] a[8] - 419 (a[4] + a[5]) a[9]) - 
   a[2] (908464951 a[4] + 64287589 a[6] + 
      651525 (5921 a[7] + 419 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[6] ((3896 + 7527 a[2]) a[7] + (3896 - 7527 a[1]) a[8]) + 
   a[5] (-(1948 + 7527 a[3]) a[7] + (-3896 + 7527 a[1]) a[9]) + 
   a[4] ((1948 + 7527 a[3]) a[8] - (3896 + 7527 a[2]) a[9]))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (-2 a[3] (a[7] + a[5] a[7] + a[8] - a[4] a[8]) + 
   a[2] ((1 + 2 a[6]) a[7] - 2 (-1 + a[4]) a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-(1 + 2 a[6]) a[8] + 2 (1 + a[5]) a[9]))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 0 && (
2 a[3] (a[4] + a[5]) + a[1] (a[5] - 2 a[6]) - 
 a[2] (a[4] + 2 a[6]))/(
a[3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
 a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
2 && (-1948 a[5] a[7] + 3896 a[6] a[7] + 1948 a[4] a[8] + 
   3896 a[6] a[8] + 419 a[1] a[6] a[8] + 
   a[1] (45 a[5] - 90 a[6] + 3928 a[8]) + 
   a[3] (a[5] (90 + 419 a[7]) + a[4] (90 - 419 a[8]) + 
      7856 (a[7] + a[8])) - (3896 (a[4] + a[5]) + 
      a[1] (7856 + 419 a[5])) a[9] + 
   a[2] (-a[6] (90 + 419 a[7]) - 3928 (a[7] + 2 a[9]) + 
      a[4] (-45 + 419 a[9])))/(a[3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + 
   a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[6] (7856 (-1 + a[2]) a[7] + (3567 - 7856 a[1]) a[8]) + 
   a[5] (3928 (1 - 2 a[3]) a[7] + (-3567 + 7856 a[1]) a[9]) + 
   3928 a[4] ((-1 + 2 a[3]) a[8] - 2 (-1 + a[2]) a[9]))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[3] ((7856 - 3567 a[5]) a[7] + 3567 (-1 + a[4]) a[8]) + 
   a[2] ((-3928 + 3567 a[6]) a[7] - 3567 (-1 + a[4]) a[9]) + 
   a[1] ((3928 - 3567 a[6]) a[8] + (-7856 + 3567 a[5]) a[9]))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 0 && 
7856 + (a[3] (-7856 a[4] + 3567 a[5]) + 
  a[2] (3928 a[4] - 3567 a[6]) - 3928 a[1] (a[5] - 2 a[6]))/(
 a[3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
  a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[3] (a[5] (160515 - 1645832 a[7]) - 
      3928 (7856 a[7] - 3567 a[8]) + 3928 a[4] (-90 + 419 a[8])) +
    a[2] (a[6] (-160515 + 1645832 a[7]) + 
      3928 (3928 a[7] - 3567 a[9]) - 
      3928 a[4] (-45 + 419 a[9])) + 
   4 (487 (3928 a[5] a[7] - 7856 a[6] a[7] + 3567 a[6] a[8] - 
         3928 a[4] (a[8] - 2 a[9]) - 3567 a[5] a[9]) + 
      982 a[1] (a[6] (90 - 419 a[8]) - 3928 (a[8] - 2 a[9]) + 
         a[5] (-45 + 419 a[9]))))/(a[3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) +
    a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[6] (-(11333 + 90 a[2]) a[7] + 90 (1 + a[1]) a[8]) - 
   45 a[5] ((1 - 2 a[3]) a[7] + 2 (1 + a[1]) a[9]) + 
   a[4] (45 (1 - 2 a[3]) a[8] + (11333 + 90 a[2]) a[9]))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (a[3] ((11333 - 90 a[5]) a[7] + 90 (-1 + a[4]) a[8]) + 
   45 a[2] ((1 + 2 a[6]) a[7] - 2 (-1 + a[4]) a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-45 (1 + 2 a[6]) a[8] + (-11333 + 90 a[5]) a[9]))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 0 && 11333 + (
 a[3] (-11333 a[4] + 90 a[5]) - 45 a[2] (a[4] + 2 a[6]) + 
  a[1] (45 a[5] + 11333 a[6]))/(
 a[3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
  a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (87660 a[5] a[7] + 22076684 a[6] a[7] - 87660 a[4] a[8] - 
   175320 a[6] a[8] - 18855 a[1] a[6] a[8] - 
   45 a[1] (45 a[5] + 11333 a[6] + 3928 a[8]) + 
   a[3] (-45 a[5] (90 + 419 a[7]) + 3928 (11333 a[7] - 90 a[8]) + 
      45 a[4] (11333 + 419 a[8])) + (-45332 (982 a[1] + 
         487 a[4]) + 45 (3896 + 419 a[1]) a[5]) a[9] + 
   45 a[2] (a[6] (90 + 419 a[7]) + a[4] (45 - 419 a[9]) + 
      3928 (a[7] + 2 a[9])))/(a[3] (a[5] a[7] - a[4] a[8]) + 
   a[2] (-a[6] a[7] + a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (a[6] a[8] - a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (-419 a[6] (a[7] - a[2] a[7] + a[8] + a[1] a[8]) + 
   a[5] ((5921 - 419 a[3]) a[7] + 419 (1 + a[1]) a[9]) + 
   a[4] ((-5921 + 419 a[3]) a[8] - 419 (-1 + a[2]) a[9]))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (419 a[3] (a[7] + a[5] a[7] + a[8] - a[4] a[8]) + 
   a[2] (-(5921 + 419 a[6]) a[7] + 419 (-1 + a[4]) a[9]) + 
   a[1] ((5921 + 419 a[6]) a[8] - 419 (1 + a[5]) a[9]))/(a[
     3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 0 && 419 + (-419 a[3] (a[4] + a[5]) + a[2] (5921 a[4] + 419 a[6]) + a[1] (-5921 a[5] + 419 a[6]))/(
 a[3] (-a[5] a[7] + a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (a[6] a[7] - a[4] a[9]) + 
  a[1] (-a[6] a[8] + a[5] a[9])) >= 
0 && (-11534108 a[5] a[7] + 816212 a[6] a[7] + 
   11534108 a[4] a[8] + 816212 a[6] a[8] + 
   2480899 a[1] a[6] a[8] + 
   a[1] (266445 a[5] - 18855 a[6] + 23257688 a[8]) - 
   419 a[3] (-a[5] (45 + 5921 a[7]) - 3928 (a[7] + a[8]) + 
      a[4] (-45 + 5921 a[8])) - 
   419 (1948 (a[4] + a[5]) + a[1] (3928 + 5921 a[5])) a[9] + 
   a[2] (-419 a[6] (45 + 5921 a[7]) + 
      5921 a[4] (-45 + 419 a[9]) - 
      3928 (5921 a[7] + 419 a[9])))/(a[
     3] (a[5] a[7] - a[4] a[8]) + a[2] (-a[6] a[7] + a[4] a[9]) + 
   a[1] (a[6] a[8] - a[5] a[9])) >= 0;
vars2 = a /@ Range[9];
cons2 = And @@ Thread[-8 <= vars2 <= 8];
(soln3 = NMinimize[{Total[List @@ expr2[[All, 1]]], expr2 && cons2}, 
 vars2, Reals]) // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming
expr2 && cons2 /. soln3[[2]]
(soln4 = NMaximize[{Total[List @@ expr2[[All, 1]]], expr2 && cons2}, 
 vars2, Reals]) // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming
expr2 && cons2 /. soln4[[2]]
```

Comment: Hard to start without (1) actual input code and (2) some indication of what has already been tried.

Comment: Basically I have a singular square matrix U of size n=3, which is linear combination of m variables (maybe m=4) .
For ex :- U = {{ a[1]-a[2] , a[2]+2 a[3] ,a[1]-a[2]+a[4] } , { ... } , { ... } }
The elements of group inverse of U is found to be nonlinear.
1. I want to find such values of a[i]'s, such that every element of group inverse of U is non negative
2. There is another matrix V which is derived from U but is again non linear, and I want all elements of V also to be non negative
Condition 1 gives 9 inequalities and condition 2 gives another 9 inequalities.
My aim is to find a[i]'s.

Comment: What I did so far is, I create matrix 'cond' which is a 1d array containing all these 18 conditions.
I randomly generate possible values of a[i]'s using RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 4];
I substitute in cond, and use AllTrue[cond,TrueQ] to check whether all are true

Comment: Here as inequalities are more this method to do search randomly seems inefficient. It would be great if you could suggest me any iteration based optimization technique which will be best in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html)?

```
expr = (465 a1 - 155 a2 + 1639 (-3 a3 + a4))/(-a2 a3 + a1 a4) >= 
    0 && (129 a1 - 43 a2 + 1529 (-3 a3 + a4))/(-a2 a3 + a1 a4) >= 
    0 && (525 a1 - 175 a2 + 1727 (-3 a3 + a4))/(-a2 a3 + a1 a4) >= 
    0 && (2325 a1 + 14570 a2 + 1639 (15 a3 + 94 a4))/(a2 a3 - a1 a4) >= 
    0 && (645 a1 + 4042 a2 - 1529 (15 a3 + 94 a4))/(a2 a3 - a1 a4) >= 
    0 && (2625 a1 + 16450 a2 - 1727 (15 a3 + 94 a4))/(a2 a3 - a1 a4) >= 
    0 && (17205 a1 + 4495 a2 - 1639 (111 a3 + 29 a4))/(-a2 a3 + a1 a4) >= 
    0 && (4773 a1 + 1247 a2 - 1529 (111 a3 + 29 a4))/(-a2 a3 + a1 a4) >= 0;

vars = Variables[Level[expr, {-1}]];

cons = And @@ Thread[-5 <= vars <= 5];

soln = FindInstance[expr && cons, vars, Reals] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {16.1054, {{a1 -> 1, a2 -> -1, a3 -> 0, a4 -> 5/128}}} *)

expr && cons /. soln[[2, 1]]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** Since all of the terms of the expression are positive you can minimize their constrained sum using [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)

```
(soln = NMinimize[{Total[List @@ expr[[All, 1]]], expr && cons}, vars, 
    Reals]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.889857, {51083., {a1 -> 5., a2 -> 5., a3 -> 0.771815, a4 -> -0.671466}}} *)

expr && cons /. soln[[2]]

(* True *)
```

This took less than a second.

**EDIT 2:** Or for another feasible solution, use [`NMaximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html)

```
(soln2 = NMaximize[{Total[List @@ expr[[All, 1]]], expr && cons}, vars, 
    Reals]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.674628, {6.54203*10^6, {a1 -> -0.369107, a2 -> 1.52646, a3 -> -0.00488266, 
   a4 -> 0.0398728}}} *)

expr && cons /. soln2[[2]]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT 3:** With the full set of 18 inequalities

```
expr2 = (31 a[1] + 31 a[2] - 258 (a[3] + a[4]))/(-a[2] a[3] + 
       a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (121 a[1] + 121 a[2] - 340 (a[3] + a[4]))/(-a[2] a[3] + 
       a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (208 a[1] + 208 a[2] - 1207 (a[3] + a[4]))/(-a[2] a[3] + 
       a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (341 a[1] - 6200 a[2] - 2838 a[3] + 51600 a[4])/(-a[2] a[3] +
        a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (1331 a[1] - 24200 a[2] - 3740 a[3] + 
       68000 a[4])/(-a[2] a[3] + a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (2288 a[1] - 41600 a[2] + 
       1207 (-11 a[3] + 200 a[4]))/(-a[2] a[3] + a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (3503 a[1] - 3038 a[2] + 
       258 (-113 a[3] + 98 a[4]))/(-a[2] a[3] + a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (13673 a[1] - 11858 a[2] + 
       340 (-113 a[3] + 98 a[4]))/(-a[2] a[3] + a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (23504 a[1] - 20384 a[2] - 
       1207 (113 a[3] - 98 a[4]))/(-a[2] a[3] + a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && ((204 - 109 a[2]) a[3] + (204 + 109 a[1]) a[4])/(-a[2] a[3] +
        a[1] a[4]) >= 0 && (a[1] + a[2])/(a[2] a[3] - a[1] a[4]) >= 
    1 && (a[2] (11 + 98 a[3]) + a[1] (11 - 98 a[4]) - 
       204 (a[3] + a[4]))/(a[2] a[3] - a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (-11 (2 + a[2]) a[3] + (400 + 11 a[1]) a[4])/(a[2] a[3] - 
       a[1] a[4]) >= 0 && 
   200 + (11 a[1] - 200 a[2])/(a[2] a[3] - a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (-2244 a[3] + 22 a[2] (-100 + 49 a[3]) + 
       11 a[1] (11 - 98 a[4]) + 40800 a[4])/(a[2] a[3] - a[1] a[4]) >=
     0 && ((113 - 49 a[2]) a[3] + 49 (-2 + a[1]) a[4])/(-a[2] a[3] + 
       a[1] a[4]) >= 0 && 
   98 + (113 a[1] - 98 a[2])/(a[2] a[3] - a[1] a[4]) >= 
    0 && (113 a[1] (11 - 98 a[4]) + 
       2 (-11526 a[3] + 49 a[2] (-11 + 113 a[3]) + 9996 a[4]))/(a[
         2] a[3] - a[1] a[4]) >= 0;

vars2 = a /@ Range[4];

cons2 = And @@ Thread[-5 <= vars2 <= 5];

(soln3 = NMinimize[{Total[List @@ expr2[[All, 1]]], expr2 && cons2}, 
     vars2, Reals]) // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

(* {6.23783, {64035.4, {a[1] -> 5., a[2] -> 4.75051, a[3] -> 2.77941, 
   a[4] -> 0.690623}}} *)

expr2 && cons2 /. soln3[[2]]

(* True *)

(soln4 = NMaximize[{Total[List @@ expr2[[All, 1]]], expr2 && cons2}, 
     vars2, Reals]) // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

(* {5.99586, {186403., {a[1] -> 1.78057*10^-9, a[2] -> 2.08163, 
   a[3] -> 1., a[4] -> 0.112245}}} *)

expr2 && cons2 /. soln4[[2]]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Sir, maybe 8 inequations gives result, but I have 18 inequations, 
Moreover I tried your piece of code using all 18 inequalities and it is running since 5 minutes. You can get the typed conditions, from the code I added recently.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, its working really great in this case. I will implement this method in bigger problems and I hope this works so nice.
I again thank you a lot.

Comment: Sir, In bigger problem, NMinimize is throwing error that :
"The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points. 
Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may
provide a better solution." I guess it is not able to get a feasible initial condition maybe it is encountering 1/0 form. What can be done in that case

Comment: @PushpenduGhosh - I just used `Quiet` to silence the error messages and verified the solution. As long as the solution verifies, then transient problems getting there are not a concern. Even if the `NMinimize` solution were to fail to verify, as long as the other (`NMaximize`) approach provides a feasible solution, then you have met the minimum stated requirement of finding a feasible solution.

Comment: I uploaded the code (which I created using the code template given by you, to solve a bigger problem), but neither of NMinimize nor Nmaximize is giving feasible solution.

Comment: @PushpenduGhosh - You keep moving the goalposts. From 8 to 18 to 32 inequalities and from 4 to 9 variables. Recommend that you open a new question with the revised data, linking back to this post as the initial starting point. This may get more interest in your problem from a wider audience.